# bibtext references not processing in bookdown

Tags: r-markdown, bibtex, bookdown

I have a bookdown document that cites other documents using a bibtex bibliography file. It appears to no process at all, since the output (both gitbook format and pdf) don't translate the actual citation to a reference. The output always copies the plain text of the citation, not the actual reference, like this:

[image]

Here's a minimal reproducing example, which I build using:

```
Rscript -e 'bookdown::render_book("index.Rmd", "bookdown::gitbook")'
```

index.Rmd:

````
---
title: "test"
site: "bookdown::bookdown_site"
documentclass: book
bibliography: test.bib
biblio-style: apalike
link-citations: true
# toc: yes
# toc_depth: 2
---

# Introduction {#ch:intro}

Conference publication takes the lead role in describing innovative research,
while journals are often delegated to archival purposes [@vrettas15:conferences].


```{r echo=FALSE}
sessionInfo()
```
````

test:bib:

```
@article{vrettas15:conferences,
  title =    {Conferences versus journals in computer science},
  author =   {Vrettas, George and Sanderson, Mark},
  journal =  {Journal of the Association for Information Science and Technology},
  volume =   66,
  number =   12,
  pages =    {2674--2684},
  year =     2015,
  publisher =    {Wiley Online Library}
}
```

_bookdown.yml:

```
rmd_files: [
  "index.Rmd",
]
new_session: no
bookdown::gitbook:
  split_bib: no
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out to be due to the too low version of Pandoc. A version 1.19.x or higher should fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks, Yihui. Even after eliminating the first block the result is the same.

Comment: What is your `rmarkdown::pandoc_version()`? I suspect it is too low. RStudio currently bundles Pandoc 1.19.x. If you don't use RStudio and your system's Pandoc version is lower than that, you may consider upgrading Pandoc. I tested your example in RStudio and was not able to reproduce the issue.

Comment: You're right!
the latest version for my distro (Mint 18.2) was pandoc 1.16.0.2. I downloaded and installed the latest package (pandoc 2.2.0) and now it just works.
Much obliged!